# search for custom header value in notmuch

Tags: email, search-engine

Is it possible to search for emails containing a specific custom header value using [notmuch](https://notmuchmail.org/)?

I know it's possible to search for standard headers like

```
notmuch search from:alice subject:hello to:bob@example.com
```

but is there a way to search for something like this?

```
notmuch search Accept-Language:en-US X-Spam-Flag:NO
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible since [notmuch 0.29](https://notmuchmail.org/news/release-0.29/) - see man pages for [notmuch-config(1)](https://notmuchmail.org/manpages/notmuch-config-1/)

```
   index.header.<prefix> [STORED IN DATABASE]
          Define  the  query  prefix <prefix>, based on a mail header. For
          example index.header.List=List-Id will add a probabilistic  pre‐
          fix  List:  that  searches the List-Id field.  User defined pre‐
          fixes must not start with 'a'...'z'; in particular adding a pre‐
          fix  with same name as a predefined prefix is not supported. See
          notmuch-search-terms(7) for a list of existing prefixes, and  an
          explanation of probabilistic prefixes.
```

As mentioned in the manual it's stored in the database - similar to custom queries. You have to set it for every header you want to search.

So in the case mentioned in Your question:

```
notmuch config set index.header.AcceptLanguage Accept-Language
notmuch config set index.header.XSpamFlag X-Spam-Flag
```

It's possible you would need to reindex your database
`notmuch reindex '*'`

and finally runing the search

`notmuch search AcceptLanguage:en-US AND XSpamFlag:NO`